# How kriging variance is calculated in R gstat?

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics, kriging, gstat

How does exactly the `krige` function (a wrapper to `gstat` and `predict` functions) from package `gstat` calculate kriging variance (minimized estimation variance) in Ordinary Kriging?

I wanted to reproduce in R results from [How to make a prediction in Kriging using a semivariogram?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270274/how-to-make-a-prediction-in-kriging-using-a-semivariogram/301362#301362) (prediction equal to 6.88 and kriging variance equal to 3.14). Here is the R code for the same set of points and covariance function.

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)

p = SpatialPoints(cbind(c(0,0,3),c(0,2,1)))
p$z = c(10,7,3)
krige(z~1, p, SpatialPoints(cbind(1,1)), vgm(psill=3, nugget=1, range=6, "Exp"))

#Results
[using ordinary kriging]
  coordinates  var1.pred var1.var
1      (1, 1)  6.813431  2.002507
```

The prediction result is close (6.88 *versus* 6.81), but the kriging variance is very different (3.14 *versus* 2, even though the variance unit is squared which partially explains a greater difference).

The example I used in the linked post was made up, yet I also have tested examples from two other sources and was not able to reproduce results with `krige` as well (though results were a little more proximate than mine). What am I missing?

The equation used to calculate the kriging variance in the example was:

```
σ²ε = sill - [w1 ... wn λ] [C10]
                           |...|
                           |Cn0|
                           [1  ]
```

where `σ²ε` is the kriging variance, `sill` is the variogram sill parameter, `wn` the kriging weight of sample point `n` , `λ` is the Lagrange multiplier, `Cn0` is the covariance between sample point `n` and prediction point.

A bonus question is, should the predicted values (6.88 versus 6.81) have been the same as well?

Looking at `krige` and `predict` source codes did not help because they are over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a difference in the variogram between the model fitted here with `gstat` and the one in the linked question.

In the linked question, the model is expressed in terms of the covariance as C:

```
C(h) = σ² = 4, if |h| = 0
C(h) = (σ² - a)exp(-3|h|/r) = (4 - 1)exp(-3|h|/6), if |h| > 0
```

In R,

```
C = function(h){3*exp(-3*h/6)}
```

And the variogram from that covariance is `σ²-C(h)`:

```
VC = function(h){4-C(h)}
```

Compare that with the variogram from `gstat`:

```
VCgstat = vgm(psill=3, nugget=1, range=6, "Exp")
plot(variogramLine(VCgstat,maxdist=50), type="l")
lines(0:50, VC(0:50), col="red")
```

[image]

I suspect this difference is a difference in the definition of "range" for the model. I don't think there is a clear agreement on the meaning of "range" for exponential variograms.

A little experimenting with the range parameter of the gstat model shows it is exactly equal to the `VC` function when `range=2`:

```
VCgstat2 = vgm(psill=3, nugget=1, range=2, "Exp")
```

And if I `krige` using that I get close agreement with the linked post:

```
> krige(z~1, p, SpatialPoints(cbind(1,1)), vgm(psill=3, nugget=1, range=2, "Exp"))
[using ordinary kriging]
  coordinates var1.pred var1.var
1      (1, 1)  6.887426 3.136307
```

I'm not sure where this change has come from - possibly there's a multiply by sigma-squared minus 1 that shouldn't be there - but you should always carefully read (and then check!) the meaning of all parameters.

Comment: You nailed it. `vgm` takes the exponential model as `C(h) = (σ² - a)*exp(-|h|/r)` (or `S(h) = a + (σ² -  a)*(1-exp(-[h]/r)`), i.e., 'range' is approximate one third from the dist where the variogram curve flattens. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153931/getting-range-value-from-exponential-variogram-model. Thank you.